# FME 2015.1.01 and SQL Server 2012 Native Client Issues

Tags: sql-server, fme-form

I'm having trouble connecting to a SQL Server 2008 database from FME 2015.1.01 on a computer with SQL Server Management Studio 2012, including SQL Server Native Client.

Here's the error message:

```
MS SQL Server Reader: Failed to connect using SQL Server 2012 Native Client, trying to use SQL Server 2008 Native Client. Provider error '(-2146824582) Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.'. Connection string 'Provider=SQLNCLI10;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Data Source=TNSV05;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=XXX;Password=********'
MS SQL Server Reader: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client is available at http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=29065
MS SQL Server Reader: Connection failed.  Connection string `Provider=SQLNCLI10;DataTypeCompatibility=80;Data Source=TNSV05;Initial Catalog=XXXX;User ID=XXXX;Password=********'. Provider error `(-2146824582) Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.'
MS SQL Server Reader: Ensure Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 2008 or 2012 is installed
UniversalReader -- readSchema resulted in 0 schema features being returned
```

The error indicates that the NACL needs to be installed, but it definitely is.

[image: SQL Server Native Client]

Any ideas?

Edit: it's the 64 bit version of FME.

Comment: 32bit or 64 bit FME 2015.1?

Comment: 64 bit, using 64 bit sqlncli installer and checked odbcad to see if they drivers were available for both 32 and 64 bit apps...

Comment: would send a ticket into safe support - they are quick to respond.